# Twilio Voicemail (forwading to cell phone)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I am currently building a call forwarding system with Twilio. I am routing calls to my cell phone. The problem I am having is with the voicemail. My regular cell phones voicemail will pickup sometimes where I want to play  a custom message of the business they are calling.

I understand you can use the dial time out. But, I've found that in cases where two calls are coming in on top of each other or in other instances it will still end up going to the regular cell phones voicemail.

My question is, is there any other way around this? I could press a button when I answer like 1 or something if that would work. But, I'm just not seeing a way of doing this. Ideally I would want a 100% success rate with forwarding to the proper voicemail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want human detection, you can find more details at the link below, but you use the Dial verb with [Number Noun URL parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url) (Whisper) and Say/Gather verbs to announce yourself to the dialed party and have them enter any key to answer the call. If they don't enter a key, you know it was the voicemail that answered and direct the inbound call accordingly.

[Alternatives to AMD](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132567-Can-Twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine-)

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what i was looking for.